# Dictionary unpacking doesn't work in one arm of a ternary expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable-unpacking

I'd like to do something like the following (obviously with a proper condition rather than just True):

```
a = {1:1}
print({2:2, **a if True else 1:0})
```

however, it doesn't work:

```
$ python3 test2.py 
  File "test2.py", line 2
    print({2:2, **a if True else 1:0})
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It also doesn't work if I put the dictionary unpacking in parens (I thought maybe there was a precedence issue between the unpacking and the ternary expression):

```
$ python3 test2.py 
  File "test2.py", line 2
    print({2:2, (**a) if True else 1:0})
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

In the end, I had to apply the unpacking to the whole ternary expression, and use a temporary dictionary for the default:

```
a = {1:1}
print({2:2, **(a if True else {1:0})})
```

(which gives the output `{2: 2, 1: 1}`)

Why can a ternary expression not contain a dictionary unpacking?

Comment: `print(a if True else {1:0})` ?

Comment: @Rakesh I just updated the question to show why that doesn't work - I want to add additional values to the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax.

```
a = {1:1}
a.update({2:2} if True else {1:0})
print(a)
```

**Output:**

```
{1: 1, 2: 2}
```